# how to add another add to cart button in product page in magento2

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I want to add customize add to add button near add to cart button and on that click, the product should add in the cart in magento2
I have followed this link:[magento 2 Adding one more Add to cart button](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155728/magento-2-adding-one-more-add-to-cart-button) but no output is coming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the below file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

to your theme like below:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

**Add This For Secound Button :-**

```
<div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
```